# Writing C++ templates to evaluate expression - pointer errors?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing C++ templates to evaluate expressions with variables. Basically, for a structure like (x+5)*(x-2) it will evaluate the whole expression for any variable x. Here's the relevant code:

.cpp file:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){

    int x = 5;
    typedef MULTIPLY <
        ADD < VAR, LIT<5> >,
        SUBSTRACT < VAR, LIT<2> >
    >
    EXPRESSION;

    EXPRESSION e;

    printf("(x+5)*(x-2) = %d for x=%d", e.eval(x), x);

    return 0;

}
```

header file:

```
struct VAR{
    static inline int eval(int i){ return i; };
};

template<int INT>
struct LIT{
    static inline int eval(int i){ return INT; };
};

template<class L, class R>
struct ADD{
    static inline int eval(int i){
        return L::eval(i) + R::eval(i);
    };
};

template<class L, class R>
struct SUBSTRACT{
    static inline int eval(int i){
        return L::eval(i) - R::eval(i);
    };
};

template<class L, class R>
struct MULTIPLY{
    static inline int eval(int i){
        return L::eval(i) * R::eval(i);
    };
};
```

Which when executed correctly prints out

```
(x+5)*(x-2) = 30 for x=5
```

Now, I'm trying to expand this code to accept an array of variables. So

```
int arr[2] = {1,2};
```

given to

```
(x+y)
```

should put the variables in order and calculate the same thing using the 2 (or any number of) separate values from the array (super simple example).

.cpp file:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){

    int arr[2] = {1,2};
    typedef ADD < VARS<2>, VARS<2> >
    EXPRESSION;

    EXPRESSION e;

    printf("(x+y) = %d\n", e.eval(arr));

    return 0;

}
```

and this is where I get stuck. This is what I have in the header file:

```
//take an array arr[] of size N
template<int N>
struct VARS{
    static inline int eval(int arr[]){
        //go for next value
        VARS<N-1>::eval(arr+1);
        //end return current one
        return arr[0];
    };
};

// if array size = 0, end execution
template<>
struct VARS<0>{
    static inline int eval(int arr[]){ return 0; };
};

template<class L, class R>
struct ADD{
    static inline int eval(int i){
        return L::eval(i) + R::eval(i);
    };
};
```

but when I try to compile it I get a bunch of errors:

```
ExpressionTemplate.cpp: In function 'int main(int, const char**)':
ExpressionTemplate.cpp:17:35: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
  printf("(x+y) = %d\n", e.eval(arr));
                                   ^
In file included from ExpressionTemplate.cpp:5:0:
ExpressionTemplate.h:19:23: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'static int ADD<L, R>::eval(int) [with L = VARS<2>; R = VARS<2>]'
     static inline int eval(int i){
                       ^
ExpressionTemplate.h: In instantiation of 'static int ADD<L, R>::eval(int) [with L = VARS<2>; R = VARS<2>]':
ExpressionTemplate.cpp:17:35:   required from here
ExpressionTemplate.h:20:23: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
         return L::eval(i) + R::eval(i);
                       ^
ExpressionTemplate.h:6:23: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'static int VARS<N>::eval(int*) [with int N = 2]'
     static inline int eval(int arr[]){
                       ^
ExpressionTemplate.h:20:36: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
         return L::eval(i) + R::eval(i);
                                    ^
ExpressionTemplate.h:6:23: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'static int VARS<N>::eval(int*) [with int N = 2]'
     static inline int eval(int arr[]){
```

Any help will be most appreciated :)

Comment: Not sure how you expect your code to work. There is only one version of `eval` inside `ADD`, and it takes `int`, not a pointer to `int` (to which your array decays).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is passing an array of `int`s (which decays into an `int*`) into your `ADD`'s `eval` function. But you defined `ADD::eval` to take a single `int`. You would need to add another function to `ADD` to account for the case when you pass an array in, or make a new class (ie. `VAR_ADD`) to handle this case.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! Still new to C++ and the whole pointers thing.